# How can I connect a mySQL database file by using JSP in Spring MVC?(Also Hibernate used.)

Tags: hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

Do you advice any tutorial or example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put it in a JSP; that logic belongs in a service.  The service is called by a controller, which is mapped to a particular request from a JSP.

Lots of examples from Spring docs:

- [Spring JDBC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/jdbc.html)
- [Spring MVC step by step](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/)

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a MySQL database with Java you clearly need to understand [JDBC fundamentals](http://www.jdbc-tutorial.com/) first: specially, how to connect to a Database.

Then you can start worrying about connecting to your MySQL DataBase within SpringMVC or a JSP file. To do that, you will need to provide information about what Application Server you are using.